# How can you do SQL joins on dates between specific dates?

Tags: google-bigquery

This may be incredibly hard or incredibly simple, I don't know which but I'm stuck.

How do I join data that happened between specific days? How do I write that? The tricky thing is that every row would have a different time period, a unique period for every user. Example:

Table A
[image]

Table B

[image]

Table C (the one I would like to get)

[image]

I am using Google BigQuery if anyone is wondering

Comment: thanks anyway. I knew this was too hard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql))

```
SELECT 
  a.User_Id, Start_date, End_Date, 
  (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(clicks),0) FROM TableB WHERE user_Id = a.User_Id 
  AND date BETWEEN Start_date AND End_date) AS Clicks_from_tableB
FROM TableA AS a
ORDER BY user_Id
```

or

```
SELECT 
  a.User_Id, Start_date, End_Date, 
  SUM(IFNULL(clicks, 0))  AS Clicks_from_tableB
FROM TableA AS a
LEFT JOIN TableB AS b
ON a.User_Id = b.User_Id
AND b.date BETWEEN Start_date AND End_date
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY user_Id
```